# How do I choose grid and block dimensions for CUDA kernels?

Tags: performance, optimization, cuda, gpu, nvidia

This is a question about how to determine the CUDA grid, block and thread sizes. This is an additional question to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5643838/1292251).

Following this link, the answer from talonmies contains a code snippet (see below). I don't understand the comment "value usually chosen by tuning and hardware constraints".

I haven't found a good explanation or clarification that explains this in the CUDA documentation. In summary, my question is how to determine the optimal `blocksize` (number of threads) given the following code:

```
const int n = 128 * 1024;
int blocksize = 512; // value usually chosen by tuning and hardware constraints
int nblocks = n / nthreads; // value determine by block size and total work
madd<<<nblocks,blocksize>>>mAdd(A,B,C,n);
```

Answer (score 180, accepted):

There are two parts to that answer (I wrote it). One part is easy to quantify, the other is more empirical.

### Hardware Constraints:

This is the easy to quantify part. Appendix F of the current CUDA programming guide lists a number of hard limits which limit how many threads per block a kernel launch can have. If you exceed any of these, your kernel will never run. They can be roughly summarized as:

1. Each block cannot have more than 512/1024 threads in total ([Compute Capability](http://www.geeks3d.com/20100606/gpu-computing-nvidia-cuda-compute-capability-comparative-table/) 1.x or 2.x and later respectively)
2. The maximum dimensions of each block are limited to
   [512,512,64]/[1024,1024,64] (Compute 1.x/2.x or later)
3. Each block cannot consume more than 8k/16k/32k/64k/32k/64k/32k/64k/32k/64k registers total
   (Compute 1.0,1.1/1.2,1.3/2.x-/3.0/3.2/3.5-5.2/5.3/6-6.1/6.2/7.0)
4. Each block cannot consume more than 16kb/48kb/96kb of shared memory (Compute
   1.x/2.x-6.2/7.0)

If you stay within those limits, any kernel you can successfully compile will launch without error.

### Performance Tuning:

This is the empirical part. The number of threads per block you choose within the hardware constraints outlined above can and does effect the performance of code running on the hardware. How each code behaves will be different and the only real way to quantify it is by careful benchmarking and profiling. But again, very roughly summarized:

1. The number of threads per block should be a round multiple of the warp size, which is 32 on all current hardware.
2. Each streaming multiprocessor unit on the GPU must have enough active warps to sufficiently hide all of the different memory and instruction pipeline latency of the architecture and achieve maximum throughput. The orthodox approach here is to try achieving optimal hardware occupancy (what [Roger Dahl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9986071/681865) is referring to).

The second point is a huge topic which I doubt anyone is going to try and cover it in a single StackOverflow answer. There are people writing PhD theses around the quantitative analysis of aspects of the problem (see [this presentation](http://www.nvidia.com/content/gtc-2010/pdfs/2238_gtc2010.pdf) by Vasily Volkov from UC Berkley and [this paper](http://www.stuffedcow.net/research/cudabmk) by Henry Wong from the University of Toronto for examples of how complex the question really is).

At the entry level, you should mostly be aware that the block size you choose (within the range of legal block sizes defined by the constraints above) can and does have a impact on how fast your code will run, but it depends on the hardware you have and the code you are running. By benchmarking, you will probably find that most non-trivial code has a "sweet spot" in the 128-512 threads per block range, but it will require some analysis on your part to find where that is. The good news is that because you are working in multiples of the warp size, the search space is very finite and the best configuration for a given piece of code relatively easy to find.

Comment: "The number of threads per block must be a round multiple of the warp size" this is not a must but you waste resources if it is not. I noticed that cudaErrorInvalidValue is returned by cudaGetLastError after a kernel launch with too many blocks (looks like compute 2.0 cannot handle 1 billion blocks, compute 5.0 can) -- so there are limits here too.

Comment: Your Vasili Volkov link is dead. I assume you liked to his September 2010: Better Performance at Lower Occupancy article (currently found at http://www.nvidia.com/content/gtc-2010/pdfs/2238_gtc2010.pdf), There's a bitbucket with code here: https://bitbucket.org/rvuduc/volkov-gtc10

Answer (score 49):

The answers above point out how the block size can impact performance and suggest a common heuristic for its choice based on occupancy maximization. Without wanting to provide *the* criterion to choose the block size, it would be worth mentioning that CUDA 6.5 (now in Release Candidate version) includes several new runtime functions to aid in occupancy calculations and launch configuration, see

[CUDA Pro Tip: Occupancy API Simplifies Launch Configuration](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-occupancy-api-simplifies-launch-configuration/)

One of the useful functions is `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize` which heuristically calculates a block size that achieves the maximum occupancy. The values provided by that function could be then used as the starting point of a manual optimization of the launch parameters. Below is a little example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/************************/
/* TEST KERNEL FUNCTION */
/************************/
__global__ void MyKernel(int *a, int *b, int *c, int N) 
{ 
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; 

    if (idx < N) { c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx]; } 
} 

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
void main() 
{ 
    const int N = 1000000;

    int blockSize;      // The launch configurator returned block size 
    int minGridSize;    // The minimum grid size needed to achieve the maximum occupancy for a full device launch 
    int gridSize;       // The actual grid size needed, based on input size 

    int* h_vec1 = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    int* h_vec2 = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    int* h_vec3 = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    int* h_vec4 = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    int* d_vec1; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_vec1, N*sizeof(int));
    int* d_vec2; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_vec2, N*sizeof(int));
    int* d_vec3; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_vec3, N*sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        h_vec1[i] = 10;
        h_vec2[i] = 20;
        h_vec4[i] = h_vec1[i] + h_vec2[i];
    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_vec1, h_vec1, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_vec2, h_vec2, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&minGridSize, &blockSize, MyKernel, 0, N); 

    // Round up according to array size 
    gridSize = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize; 

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Occupancy calculator elapsed time:  %3.3f ms \n", time);

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    MyKernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_vec1, d_vec2, d_vec3, N); 

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Kernel elapsed time:  %3.3f ms \n", time);

    printf("Blocksize %i\n", blockSize);

    cudaMemcpy(h_vec3, d_vec3, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        if (h_vec3[i] != h_vec4[i]) { printf("Error at i = %i! Host = %i; Device = %i\n", i, h_vec4[i], h_vec3[i]); return; };
    }

    printf("Test passed\n");

}
```

**EDIT**

The `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize` is defined in the `cuda_runtime.h` file and is defined as follows:

```
template<class T>
__inline__ __host__ CUDART_DEVICE cudaError_t cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(
    int    *minGridSize,
    int    *blockSize,
    T       func,
    size_t  dynamicSMemSize = 0,
    int     blockSizeLimit = 0)
{
    return cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSizeVariableSMem(minGridSize, blockSize, func, __cudaOccupancyB2DHelper(dynamicSMemSize), blockSizeLimit);
}
```

The meanings for the parameters is the following

```
minGridSize     = Suggested min grid size to achieve a full machine launch.
blockSize       = Suggested block size to achieve maximum occupancy.
func            = Kernel function.
dynamicSMemSize = Size of dynamically allocated shared memory. Of course, it is known at runtime before any kernel launch. The size of the statically allocated shared memory is not needed as it is inferred by the properties of func.
blockSizeLimit  = Maximum size for each block. In the case of 1D kernels, it can coincide with the number of input elements.
```

Note that, as of CUDA 6.5, one needs to compute one's own 2D/3D block dimensions from the 1D block size suggested by the API.

Note also that the CUDA driver API contains functionally equivalent APIs for occupancy calculation, so it is possible to use [`cuOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__OCCUPANCY.html#group__CUDA__OCCUPANCY_1g04c0bb65630f82d9b99a5ca0203ee5aa) in driver API code in the same way shown for the runtime API in the example above.

Comment: I have two questions. Firstly when should one choose grid size as  minGridSize over the manually calculated gridSize. Secondly you mentioned that "The values provided by that function could be then used as the starting point of a manual optimization of the launch parameters. " - do you mean the launch parameters still need to be manually optimized ?

Comment: Is there any guidance as to how to calculate the 2D/3D block dimensions?   In my case I'm looking for 2D block dimensions.  Is it just a case of calculing x and y factors when multiplied together give the original block size?

Comment: @GrahamDawes [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245737/cuda-estimating-threads-per-blocks-and-block-numbers-for-2d-grid-data/33247118#33247118) may be of interest.

Answer (score 10):

The blocksize is usually selected to maximize the "occupancy". Search on CUDA Occupancy for more information. In particular, see the CUDA Occupancy Calculator spreadsheet.