# cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code 4 after launching

Tags: cuda

I have written a simple matrix multiplication code using CUDA, when I run code for input size of `A(10000*10000)*B(10000*10000)`, I receive this message:

```
cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code 4 after launching
```

After adding these instructions in order to measure run time, I recieve "unspecified launch failure" error.

```
cudaEventRecord(start);
// here is my kernel call
cudaEventRecord(stop);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
```

this is my kernel call:

```
mulKernel<<<1, dataSet.threadSize>>>(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b, dataSet.n, dataSet.m, dataSet.p, dataSet.threadSize);
```

and this is my kernel code:

```
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    int j, k, sum;
    //if(n<=threadSize)
    for(; i < n; i+=threadSize){
        for(j = 0; j < p; j++){
            sum = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < m; k++){
                sum += A[i * m + k] * B[k * p + j];
            }
            C[i *p + j] = sum;
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried calling `cudaGetLastError` and `cudaGetErrorString`? These should tell you what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are launching 1 block with size `dataSet.threadSize`. This would be way more than the maximum number of threads in a block (1024 for Kepler GPU I think). Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985912/how-do-i-choose-grid-and-block-dimensions-for-cuda-kernels) on how to choose your grid and block dimensions.

Comment: This occurs even with threadSize of 512, 256 and thread size less than these numbers.

Comment: @vahid: Perhaps post more code on how you allocate memory/launch kernel.

Comment: memory allocation:
cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, (dataSet.m * dataSet.n)* sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }
memory copy:
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, dataSet.A, (dataSet.m * dataSet.n)* sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }