# What should be the minimum and maximum number of threads that i could run for a task?

Tags: multithreading

I am new to CUDA and need help understanding some things.From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035225/number-of-total-threads-blocks-and-grids-on-my-gpu) i understood 2 things.

1. 6144 is the instantaneous capacity of my GPU.
   So that while trying some multiprocessing code, i could run up to only 6144 thread? Is that correct?
2. I could create a kernel of any size (In Cuda C programming). With any block size and number of threads.

The device query is shown  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035225/number-of-total-threads-blocks-and-grids-on-my-gpu).
It will be a pleasure if i got clear clarification on these two.

Still i am confused about how many threads and blocks are there in my GPU, and also how many threads could i used to run for a task (max and min limit).

Comment: The question you linked to already has answers that seem to answer your question, can you please elaborate on what is missing in terms of your questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of total threads, blocks, and grids on my GPU.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035225/number-of-total-threads-blocks-and-grids-on-my-gpu)